# Flutter Can't generate signed Bundle or APK

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle

when trying to generate Bundle I get Generating signed Bundle requires you to update the Android Gradle plugin to version 3.2.0 or higher. I checked my Gradle version and it is `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'` .

Tried to search in interned, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you're using a Flutter version that is compatible with the Android Gradle plugin version you're using. Sometimes, compatibility issues can arise if you're using an older version of Flutter with a newer version of the Gradle plugin. You might need to update Flutter to the latest stable version.